# Make push notification from celery function

Tags: python, django, push-notification, celery

I'm trying to show a message using Django message, but this alert should be executed when a certain event happened on @shared_task.
This is my celery function code in tasks.py

```
def show_message_in_time(self,response):
    while True:
        # get_info_to_show() this function will do something 
        messages.info(response, 'Your email is added successfully!')
        sleep(2*60)
```

and this is the function on views.py

```
def index(response):
    
    show_message_in_time.delay(response)
    return render(response, "Sales.html", {'zipped_list': objs})
```

Below is the error I received

```
Exception Value:    
Object of type 'WSGIRequest' is not JSON serializable
```

I have tried to convert WSGIRequest to JSON and also that's not working.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does your `show_message_in_time` task really have to run an infinite loop?

If it just shows a message after some delay, then you might try to simply run it in a new thread (the thread will automatically die once the message is showed), e.g.:

`threading.Thread(target=show_message_in_time, args=(request,)).start()`

Since the thread will be within the same process, you won't have to serialize your `WSGIRequest` object.

Comment: i have tried before to run it with thread but Threading library now working with Django.messages , check this for more information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126586/threading-in-django-is-not-working-in-production

Comment: In that case, you might try to change the default serializer from JSON to Pickle so that you can freely pass objects of the `WSGIRequest` type to your Celery workers. Again, I'm not sure whether it will really work for you but at least it looks like just a small tweak in your Django settings (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/security.html#serializers).

Comment: Thanks i will try it , but you don't know anyway to doing the notification from celery function or any background task

Comment: Also, you might take a look at this library: https://github.com/codeinthehole/django-async-messages. What it does is that it provides your some utility functions to save to the Django cache some messages for a user (e.g. from your Celery tasks), and also a Django middleware class checking the cache to see if the user has some pending messages and showing those using `messages`.

If you're using Celery, then you must have a message broker. If it's Redis, then you can also use it as a cache for the Django caching framework. Thus, the library can be really helpful.

Comment: Sadly they said here that we can't pass WSGIRequest to @shared_task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650060/periodic-tasks-in-django-celery-how-to-notify-the-user-on-screen

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to your problem is to create a dictionary out of pieces of WSGIRequest/HttpRequest that you really need.

Let's say your WSGIRequest has "username" and "email" parts. Then you refactor your index to something like:

```
def index(response):
    data = { 
        "method": response.method,
        "username": response["username"],
        "email": response["email"]
    }

    if response.method == "POST":
        data["response_data"] = response.POST

    if response.method == "GET":
        data["response_data"] = response.GET

    show_message_in_time.delay(data)
    return render(response, "Sales.html", {'zipped_list': objs})
```

If you know it is a post method then the quickest test would be

```
def index(response):
    # POST is a dictionary, so it is definitely serializable
    show_message_in_time.delay(response.POST)
    return render(response, "Sales.html", {'zipped_list': objs})
```

Disclaimer: I never used Django or any other web framework, but I know little bit about Celery.

Comment: The request is just a GET request not POST also i found that we can't use messages on celery methods , check that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650060/periodic-tasks-in-django-celery-how-to-notify-the-user-on-screen

Comment: I did not know that - replace response.POST to response.GET and test whether it works or not. The reason why it does not work as you tried is because those objects are not serializable.

Comment: response.GET returns an empty dict